# Error: Cannot find module './Assert' When Running npm run watch with Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, npm-run

I randomly started getting this error message when I try to run `npm run watch`. I don't know what I did that would cause it to have an error since I never touched any of the files related to laravel-mix.

```
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './Assert'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Api.js:1:76)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Tried running npm update and npm install to get the latest files but it didn't help.

I even tried manually adding the Assert.js file, but I kept getting new errors with each one that I fixed. There must be a better solution.

I deleted laravel-mix from node_modules and ran npm install again and it changed my error to:

```
Error: Cannot find module './transform'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/node_modules/ajv-keywords/keywords/index.js:18:14)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ended up getting `npm run watch` to work by deleting the node_modules directory and running `npm install` to get all files fresh. Not sure why I had to delete the node_modules folder to get the fresh files, but at least its working.